# Difference between Cosmologial Constant and Quantum Vacuum State

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, cosmological-constant

Hello I am very new to cosmology and quantum physics. I need some basic understanding (in Layman's term) of the Difference between Cosmological Constant and Quantum Vacuum. Cosmological Constant is, as I read, is the dark energy which is positive. Quantum Vacuum is the lowest possible energy found in space between quarks. I wud like to know if energy density for vacuum the same for Cosmological Constant?

Answer (score 4):

The cosmological constant of classical General Relativity and the vacuum (or zero-point) energy are closely related.

The cosmological constant is simply a constant term $\Lambda$ in the Lagrangian density for the [Einstein-Hilbert action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action)
and may be interpreted as an energy density permeating all space.

In quantum field theory, one finds that the vacuum can, in principle, have a finite energy density $\chi$ (after renormalization), which is given by having a constant term $\chi$ to in the Hamiltonian density. The vacuum itself is not exactly defines as "empty space", but the quantum state which you cannot remove a particle from - it is the "emptiest" state in the theory.

In a theory with gravity, $\chi = \Lambda$ if we suppose that we *can* define the vacuum as in usual QFT. However, there are subtleties involved in choosing a vacuum in curved spacetimes, and the choice may not be unique, so the state with energy density $\Lambda$ may not be the "best" choice for a vacuum in all cases.

Nevertheless, one may heuristically expect a cosmological constant of the classical theory to be the energy density of the vacuum state of the quantum theory.

Also, because the vacuum energy density has to be renormalized, its value (and thus the value of the cosmological constant) is an *input* to the quantum field theory, and may not be predicted.